# Run Keyword If for 2 different pages - second element always not detected and failed

Tags: robotframework

the app under testing has the page flow possibilities as below:

```
- app launch -> PAGE1 (input pin1) -> DONE
or
- app launch -> PAGE1 (input pin1) -> PAGE2 (input pin2) -> DONE
or
- app launch -> PAGE2 (input pin2) -> PAGE1 (input pin1) -> DONE
```

I have written test case to wait for the element then perform different keyword.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    AppiumLibrary
Resource   ../Resources/nine-res-work.robot
Resource   ../Resources/common-mobile.robot

*** Variables ***
${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-1}   ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@resource-id="${PREFIX-ID}btn_number" and @text="1"]
${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-2}   ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@resource-id="${PREFIX-ID}btn_number" and @text="2"]

${LOGIN-PAGE1}         ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@resource-id="${PREFIX-ID}headerText" and @text="Enter your PIN."]
${LOGIN-PAGE2}         ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@resource-id="${PREFIX-ID}headerText" and @text="Enter your passcode."]


*** Keywords ***
Input PAGE1 Passcode
    Tap     ${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-1}

Input PAGE2 Passcode
    Tap     ${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-2}

*** Test Cases ***
Launch App
    Launch Application
    Sleep   5s

Input Password
    ${PAGE1}=  Run Keyword And Return Status   Page Should Contain Element    ${LOGIN-PAGE1}
    ${PAGE2}=  Run Keyword And Return Status   Page Should Contain Element    ${LOGIN-PAGE2}
    Run Keyword If      ${PAGE1}      Input PAGE1 Passcode
    Sleep   15s
    Run Keyword If      ${PAGE2}      Input PAGE2 Passcode
```

Errors occurred at

```
Page Should Contain Element ${LOGIN-PAGE2} but screenshot is page 1
```

Comment: This question seems to be an updated version of this one. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65355863/3820025 if that is the case please delete the old question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this piece here:

```
${PAGE1}=  Run Keyword And Return Status   Page Should Contain Element    ${LOGIN-PAGE1}
${PAGE2}=  Run Keyword And Return Status   Page Should Contain Element    ${LOGIN-PAGE2}
```

, you are checking is this LOGIN-PAGE1, and immediately after that - is it 2.
Say it is 1, and the variable is set to True - you are not taking any action before checking for LOGIN-PAGE2, that happens immediately. And reading your description, it can be only one of them - thus what you say is an error is actually the expected state, the screenshot is from page 1.

To fulfill this logic:

```
- app launch -> PAGE1 (input pin1) -> PAGE2 (input pin2) -> DONE
or
- app launch -> PAGE2 (input pin2) -> PAGE1 (input pin1) -> DONE
```

, this code should do:

```
Run Keyword If      ${PAGE1} and not ${PAGE2}    Run Keywords    Input PAGE1 Passcode    AND    Sleep    15s    AND    Input PAGE2 Passcode 
  ...    ELSE IF    not ${PAGE1} and ${PAGE2}    Run Keywords    Input PAGE2 Passcode    AND    Sleep    15s    AND    Input PAGE1 Passcode 
  ...    ELSE     Fail    Unexpected state.    # both variables are false, or both - true, which is not by design
```